# Textbox DLookup value sometimes missing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that has 18 unbound textboxes that pull up values.
They generally work 90% of the time.  Sometimes a value doesn't come up and the only way I can fix it is to close the database and open it back up again.

9 textboxes need to be refreshed every time a record changes

Here is an example of 2 of the 9 of the textboxes that get stuck:

```
'txtAFP_Sum
=IIf(IsError([sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totAFP]),"-",[sfm_COB_DISTR]![totAFP])
'txtALLOT_Sum
=IIf(IsError([sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totALLOT]),"-",[sfm_COB_DISTR]![totALLOT])
```

The other 7 have similar formulas.

9 other unbound textboxes do not need to change every time I view a record, so in an effort to try to speed up some of these calculations, I put wrote a routine that assigns dLookups to the unbound textboxes only when it is necessary to see the values change.

Every time I change a value that would require seeing updates to all of the boxes, I call the following routine:

```
    Public Sub RefreshTOTALS()

    PopUpMsg ("Refreshing Totals...")


    With Form_frm_COB

    'Entire COB
    .txtTOTALS_AFP = DLookup("AFP", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_ALLT = DLookup("ALLT", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_SP_C = DLookup("SP_C", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_SP_O = DLookup("SP_O", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_COMMITS = DLookup("COMMITS", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_OBS = DLookup("OBS", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_COM_SP_RATE = DLookup("COM_SP_RATE", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_OBS_SP_RATE = DLookup("OBS_SP_RATE", "TOTALS_FINAL")
    .txtTOTALS_UNC = DLookup("UNC", "TOTALS_FINAL")

    'Current COB ID
.txtAFP_Sum.Requery
.txtALLOT_Sum.Requery    
.txtSP_C.Requery
    .txtSP_O.Requery
    .txtCOMS.Requery
    .txtOBLG.Requery
    .txtSPRate.Requery
    .txtOBSRate.Requery
    .txtWBS_Remain.Requery
    End With

    End Sub
```

I'm hoping I can address what causes values not to calculate.

Comment: What data type is `totAFP` and `totALLOT`? `IsError()` is used in numerical expressions but you're setting the true scenario of `IIF()`as a string. Maybe that's interfering with the `IIF()` statement?

Comment: Yes. I was hoping for that type of an answer - the data type is Currency.  So It's the "-" .   How can I get the same effect that Excel does where it shows "-" in place of 0?

Comment: The TextBox `[sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totAFP]` seems to be on a subform. If the subform contains more than one record, then this will only display the `totAFP` of the current record. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: No.  "totAFP" sits in the footer of sfm_COB_DISTR and contains the formula Sum([AFP])

Comment: @monty327 depending on what error you are trying to avoid (I'm assuming a `Null`?) then you might be able to use `IsNull` instead of `IsError` to display the hyphen. @Olivier found an error though that is much more likely the cause of your troubles. (sorry, missed your other comment, but I think you still need to call `.Form` as you did previously in your `IIF` statement)

Answer (score 1):

In the following expressions the `.[Form]` part is missing in th else-case of `IIf`:

**wrong:**

```
'txtAFP_Sum
=IIf(IsError([sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totAFP]),"-",[sfm_COB_DISTR]![totAFP])
'txtALLOT_Sum
=IIf(IsError([sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totALLOT]),"-",[sfm_COB_DISTR]![totALLOT])
```

**corrected:**

```
'txtAFP_Sum                                                      vvvvvvv
=IIf(IsError([sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totAFP]),"-",[sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totAFP])
'txtALLOT_Sum                                                      vvvvvvv
=IIf(IsError([sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totALLOT]),"-",[sfm_COB_DISTR].[Form]![totALLOT])
```

Comment: Excellent catch.  But why does the calculation ever work?  Shouldn't it always err?

Comment: If `sfm_COB_DISTR` is the name of a subform control contained in the current form and `totAFP` is the name of a text box in the form contained in that subform control, `[sfm_COB_DISTR]![totAFP]` will give you the text box's `.Value` ... you do not need to inject `.Form` between those 2 object names.

Comment: So I guess we haven't addressed the other 10% of the time the formula gives me a "-" for no reason at all, requiring me to restart the form?